# PHP - Selecting the currently used database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having a problem in getting the string name of the currently selected database.
this is what i did.. i am trying to echo the name of the database but it produces an error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

```
<?php
$dbcon = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
        or die(mysql_error()."Not Connected");

$sql = mysql_query("select database()");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo "db ".$row[0];
```

?>

i need to get the selected database name because i will use it for

```
mysql_select_db()
```

Comment: See it http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-dbs.php

Comment: i don't understand, just do: `mysql_select_db('db', $dbcon) or die('Could not select database.');`

Comment: @ashley I need to make it dynamic, because on other page, i will be creating the database

Answer (score 4):

You should either select a database right after connecting using your login credentials. Or, if you want to see what databases the `root` user has access to, use:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

Answer (score 3):

`select Database()` shows the name of the name of the slected database.
It will work only after you have already selected the database using `mysql_select_db()`.

If you want to get the name of the databases available to you then use `SHOW DATABASES`

Comment: oic.. is it possible to select the database 'dbName' after this query "use dbName"

Comment: @Katherine yes you can but if you can use `use dbName` then why dont use `mysql_select_db`

Comment: because i also need to use mysql_select_db in other page.

Comment: @Katherine ok ..  `select database()` will work after `use dbname`. Give it a try

Comment: yes it works, but within the page only, i guess i should use session

Comment: Yes if you want to keep the name of your database on next page then either use session or you have to select database on each page

Comment: when i select database on each page, the warning "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource" shows up

Comment: No from select database i mean `use dbname` or `mysql_select_db` NOT `select databases()`... :)

Comment: yes that's what i did.. now i am having a problem in using sessions :D the "headers already sent" issue :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27238/discussion-between-new-developer-and-katherine)

Comment: session_start() on top of your page.

Answer (score 2):

You yourself need to select a database after connecting to MySQL, it's not selected by default, like this:

```
$dbcon = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
    or die(mysql_error()."Not Connected");

mysql_select_db("databasename");  # add this line

$sql = mysql_query("select database()");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo "db ".$row[0];
```

Please don't use mysql_* function as they're deprecated, instead use mysqli_*.

Answer (score 1):

first, I would suggest you use mysqli functions instead of mysql as they are being deprecated.

Then, you just select the database by adding the database name in the parameter to mysql_select_db():

```
  mysql_select_db('dbname');
```

note that another advantage of mysqli is you can specify the database in the connect string